# Using Saved Unchanged XAML Build Process File Causes Build To Fail

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, tfs-process-template, build-process-template

I am getting the following build error when using my "custom" XAML process build file:

> (-1, 0)
>   TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition >\Test2\TestProject1: 
>   Exception Message: Cannot set unknown member 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.RunScript.FailOnNonZeroExitCode'. (type XamlObjectWriterException)

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Download the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml file to local storage
2. Open the template in the XAML visual editor (in new project or standalone)
3. Save the template (*NOTE*: this adds lots of extra XAML markup for some reason)
4. Commit the template to TFS
5. Import the template into the Process section of my build definition
6. Refresh the build process file
7. Queue a build using the "new" template

I haven't seen anything on StackOverflow or the ASP.NET forums regarding this particular error message in regards to saving the exact same file and using it again.  I have resorted to editing the XAML manually so that the extra markup doesn't break my build, but I'd much rather use the Toolbox to configure my workflow.

Any thoughts as to why this would happen or why I'm getting that particular error message?

*Note:* I am using Visual Studio 2015 and TFS 2015.

Comment: Is there any error log when you save the template? Can you share the screenshot for the markups?

Comment: There is no error log when I save.  It simply adds extra markup without complaint.  The only time it errors out is when I attempt to kick off a build (returning the above error message).  Here are links to the "before" and "after" files.  [Before](https://codeshare.io/jUjqf), [After](https://codeshare.io/v4C5k)

Comment: What's the build agent version? Also 2015 or any other version like 2013?

Comment: It appears to be 2015.  We reinstalled the build controller and agent just in case.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the extra markup.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't changed 'anything' to the default ***TfvcTemplate.12.xaml*** . You can try to download a new TfvcTemplate.12.xaml  without opening it in the XAML visual editor. Just checking in the source control.

If still build fails then Try to clean TFS cash and [VS cash](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx)

1. Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is:
   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache.
2. Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is:
   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache

If build success without error, this may caused by VS. Try to reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: If I follow your steps, it works just fine.  However, my goal is to make modifications to the XAML using the designer.  I was demonstrating that if I even save the XAML without even making changes, I get tons of extra markup.  I'm trying to figure out how to use the designer without it breaking my build due to the extra junk that gets thrown in there.  Hope that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are using the built-in  XAML visual editor, it should works well without error  normally. So please try to reinstall VS, it may cause the issue.

Comment: I am using the built-in XAML visual editor, and it still added the extra markup after reinstalling Visual Studio.  From what I can tell, it seems to be "intended" behavior.  Perhaps it's upgrading the XAML to a different version or standard.  See my comment under my original question.